# Opportunity progression bar

Tags: opportunity

How to make Opportunity progression bar red in color when Opportunity gets closed.
I tried through Path Settings. But there is no option for the same. Please help me.

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible out of the box. Please vote -- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lK3MQAU

Answer (score 0):

The progress bar can't be red in full width. But one can do some changes in "Brand Color" of the "Themes and Branding" page.

[image]